# How to redefine a counter defined in a style file?

Tags: formatting, numbering

The style file contains the command

```
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

I would like to have continuous numbering of formulae like (1), (2), etc. Can this be done by a command in the file with the text (that is, without editing the style file), which will switch the already defined numbering to the desired one?

A close question: what should stand in place of *?* in the following command

```
\numberwithin{equation}{?}
```

in order to get continuous numbering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could load the [chngcntr](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/chngcntr) package and insert the instruction

```
\counterwithout{equation}{section}
```

in the preamble.

Comment: The OP should also remember that if this is for a specific Journal or similar, then don;t mess with stuff like this.